# Unterminated loop in Maple

Tags: while-loop, maple

I just cant find the error in following code for maple.
Have been searching quite long for it:

```
L:=[seq(i*0,i=0..12)];  
rond:=false;  
x:=1; 
while(rond=false)  do  
if(L[x]=1)   then rond:=true;   
else L[x]:=1;  x:=(2*x+11)mod 13;   
end if; 
end do;
```

It gives an unterminated loop error. Why?

Answer (score 1):

I get an "invalid subscript" error. After one pass through the loop, x becomes 0 (2*1+11 mod 13 = 0). Zero is not a valid index for the list L. List indices start at 1.

By the way, you should use a Vector or Array for L instead of a list. It is inefficient to make assignments to list entries, and Maple won't allow it at all when the list is long.

You can make L an Array with indices 0 through 12. Simply

```
L:= Array(0..12);
```

It is automatically initialized to 0s.

Comment: Might any1 come across this same problem, I solved it by removing the round brackets just behind while and if. Seems as you shouldn't put them there.

Also, in my code, it needs to be L[x+1] since maple starts the count from 1 and not 0.